# Регулировка яркости в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Не регулируется яркость подсветки экрана на ноутбуке (только правкой /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight) возможно ли это как-нибудь исправить или если невозможно исправить, можно ли написать скриптик, который бы изменял значение в этом файле?
"Видеокарта" встроенаая в проц (те интел hd )

Comment: Вопрос не по теме SO, вам лучше обратиться на Superuser или какой-нибудь форум. Ну или купить Мак :)

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, вопросы по администрированию линухов - онтопик.

Answer (score 2):

У меня похожая проблема была, но после выключения/включения ноута уровень яркости ставился тот который по умолчанию в настройках... 
Я не специалист по шеллскриптам, но самое простое что в голову приходит это скопировать файл intel_backlight куда-нибудь в домашнюю скрытую директорию, там его выправить, а потом в консоли:

```
sudo mv -f исправленный_intel_backlight /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight
```

Если уж на то пошло, то можно в автозагрузку добавить эту команду - надо в настройках системы залезть.

Это далеко не изящное решение, но радикальное :-)